# How to get highest value in django model for each objects

Tags: python, sql, django

Admin wants to add different challenges. Each challenge has a lot of users. each user may have a lot of likes. I want to show the winner of each challenge. For that, I need to get which candidate gets the highest likes. How can I get it? is there any way like `.count` .?
how can I use that? in which model.

**For example:**

```
challenges
1  first_contest 
2  second_contest 

candidates 
id name contest
1  jhon first_contest
2  sara second_contest
3  abi  first_contest

candidates likes
id user_id candidate_id
1  1       1
2  2       2
3  1       1
```

In this case candidate, 1 = Jhon get 2 likes so in the first contest Jhon wins. Also in the second contest, Sara gets 1 like. So I need to show the winner in the first contest. How is that?

**models.py:**

```
class Challenge(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Candidates(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image = models.FileField( upload_to="challenge_candidates/",)
  def likes_count(self):
       return self.likes.all().count() 

class CandidateLikes(models.Model):
  like = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user = 
  models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='candidate_likes')
    contest_candidates = models.ForeignKey(Candidates, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
  related_name='likes')
```

Sorry for my poor English. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to have a relationship between your `CandidatLike` model and `Challenge` model so that you can filter by challenge. A foreign key relation could be sufficient. Then you can add this query to your views

```
winner = CandidateLikes.objects.filter(challenge="your_challenge_name").order_by("like")
```

Notice that `challenge` should exist in your CandidatLike model, since we are filtering by it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a relationship between Challenge and Candidates. Let's say you would add a challenge field to Candidate:

```
class Candidates(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(Challenge, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candidates')
```

Then you can query the winner of each challenge with the highest like-count with a [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/) like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

cadidates = Candidates.objects.annotate(like_count=Count('likes')).filter(challange=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-like_count')
queryset = Challenge.objects.annotate(winner=Subquery(cadidates.values('owner__username')[:1]))
```

This will give you a Challenge result query with an annotated winner like:

```
{'id': 1, 'title': 'Challange 1', 'winner': 'username'}
```